# Excel 2002 crashes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 2002 crashes every time I enter a number. It does it for all spreadsheets even new ones. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Excel. Also, I restored my system to an older date thinking this was the result of some updates. The problem keeps happening. I am using Windows 10 and Excel has worked great for months.

Comment: I'm surprised you got it to work at all - Office 2002 isn't even compatible with Windows 7, though some managed to keep Excel limping along in XP-compatibility mode until Window 8.

Comment: Going beyond the fact that the fact Excel 2002 has worked for you so far is a fluke and an accident, you have provided no error messages, logs, events, or any other information necessary to begin to answer your question. Please find and add this and any other relevant information to your question so that we can get you a better answer than "good luck".

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 Home on an Acer desktop. The Excel is part of the Office 
Suite that has run just fine for two years. Just within the past few weeks, Excel goes into Document Recovery whenever I enter a number or even try to bold a number. There is no error message. The application just disappears and shows a recovered document when I reopen the application. This happens to all spreadsheets, even new blank sheets. I use this Excel at home for simple spreadsheets. I works just fine for my needs.  I have also tried disabling my virus protection; no success.

Comment: You need to find and open the Event Viewer and look under Windows Logs and Application, then find messages related to Excel. This is where the crashes should be recorded and where necessary information to solve the problem is most likely to be found.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking there.....nothing yet. What part would have MS Office  Apps logs?

Answer (score 1):

As Tetsujin notes, Excel 2002 (Office XP) is ancient and is not supported or compatible with Windows versions 7 and later.

If you do not wish to use a more recent version of office, you should use an alternative product such as Libre Office, Open Office, or one of the various Web/Cloud based products.

Comment: If choosing between Libre Office and Open Office stick with Libre Office because Open Office is pretty much abandon now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Libre works great with my old spreadsheets.